# Cannot sort value in pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table like this:

```py
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=['Position'], columns=['Sex'], values='SalaryMean')
```

```
Sex                               F           M
Position
-------------------------------------------------       
Accountant I                      10          20
Administrative Assistant           7           3
Area Sales Manager                21          60
BI Developer                       4          10
```

I would like to sort the value in the `F` & `M` columns.
I have tried to use

```py
pivot.sort_values(by = 'F', axis=0, ascending=False)
```

which can really sort the value in `F` but when I tried to use the similar code

```py
pivot.sort_values(by = 'M', axis=0, ascending=False)
```

it produced an error (`KeyError: 'M'`) and cannot sort the value in `M`.

Does anyone know how to sort value in both columns?

Comment: Please include the full error trackback. Just saying "it came out error" tells us nothing.

Comment: I could not replicate your problem. Both sort statements are working perfectly fine for me. Ensure that you do not have any extra spaces in column names. What is the error your are getting?

Comment: the error was " KeyError: 'M' "

Comment: Error means there is no column `M`, what is `print (pivot.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael it shows ```['F', 'M ']```, obviously there's a space in the column's name ```M``` which is the reason why I can't sort the value. thank u so much!!!